# Comparison of list of lists using Binary search in Python

Tags: python, list, binary-search

I have 2 list of lists x(1 million elements) and y(0.1 million elements) and want to get z=x-y.
each list consist of sub lists of 4 elements each, of which the first element of each sublist is sorted. The first element are strictly increasing and no duplicates are present.
Now I did this using list comprehension and it roughly takes 6.5 hrs to run it. I wanted to know what is the most time efficient way to do this, keeping in mind that my end result should also be a list of lists.

Secondly, since all my first elements are sorted I thought doing a binary search would be a better idea.
Idea of binary search - 
for ex consider I have 2 lists of size x=30 and y=10
I am looping over elements of y and comparing the first element of each sub list to that of the elemnts in x using binary search, when I find a match that sublist is deleted from the x list.
So the expected output list should contain 20 elements.But the code I have written gives me 23(it does not delete the last three matches) and I dont know whats wrong with it.
Heres the code:

```
def intersection(x,y):
    temp=x[:]
    for i in range(len(y)):
        l=0
        h=len(x)-1
        while l<h:
            mid=l+((h-l)/2)
            if y[i][0]==temp[mid][0]:
                a=y[i]
                x.remove(a)
                break
            elif y[i][0]>temp[mid][0]:
                if l==mid:
                    break
                l=mid
            elif y[i][0]<temp[mid][0]:
                h=mid
    return(x)






X-List input of 30 elements
[[1.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[2.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0]
[3.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0]
[4.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0]
[5.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[6.0, 0.0, 25.0, 10.0]
[7.0, 25.0, 0.0, 10.0]
[8.0, 50.0, 0.0, 10.0]
[9.0, 50.0, 50.0, 10.0]
[10.0, 0.0, 50.0, 10.0]
[11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0]
[13.0, 17.6776695, 17.6776695, 0.0]
[14.0, 0.0, 34.3113632, 0.0]
[15.0, 25.9780293, 50.0, 0.0]
[16.0, 50.0, 25.9780293, 0.0]
[17.0, 34.3113632, 0.0, 0.0]
[18.0, 17.6776695, 17.6776695, 10.0]
[19.0, 34.3113632, 0.0, 10.0]
[20.0, 50.0, 25.9780293, 10.0]
[21.0, 25.9780293, 50.0, 10.0]
[22.0, 0.0, 34.3113632, 10.0]
[23.0, 11.6599302, 0.0, 0.0]
[24.0, 0.0, 11.6599302, 0.0]
[25.0, 0.0, 11.6599302, 10.0]
[26.0, 11.6599302, 0.0, 10.0]
[27.0, 27.9121876, 27.9121876, 0.0]
[28.0, 27.9121876, 27.9121876, 10.0]
[29.0, 9.77920055, 9.77920055, 0.0]
[30.0, 9.77920055, 9.77920055, 10.0]]
Y -List of 10 elements
[1.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[2.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0]
[11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[13.0, 17.6776695, 17.6776695, 0.0]
[14.0, 0.0, 34.3113632, 0.0]
[17.0, 34.3113632, 0.0, 0.0]
[23.0, 11.6599302, 0.0, 0.0]
[24.0, 0.0, 11.6599302, 0.0]
[27.0, 27.9121876, 27.9121876, 0.0]
[29.0, 9.77920055, 9.77920055, 0.0]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Z list (X-Y) the result should be 20 elements but its gives length as 23 elements. it does not remove the remaining 3 elements from the list.




[[3.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0],
 [4.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0],
 [5.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [6.0, 0.0, 25.0, 10.0],
 [7.0, 25.0, 0.0, 10.0],
 [8.0, 50.0, 0.0, 10.0],
 [9.0, 50.0, 50.0, 10.0],
 [10.0, 0.0, 50.0, 10.0],
 [12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0],
 [15.0, 25.9780293, 50.0, 0.0],
 [16.0, 50.0, 25.9780293, 0.0],
 [18.0, 17.6776695, 17.6776695, 10.0],
 [19.0, 34.3113632, 0.0, 10.0],
 [20.0, 50.0, 25.9780293, 10.0],
 [21.0, 25.9780293, 50.0, 10.0],
 [22.0, 0.0, 34.3113632, 10.0],
 [24.0, 0.0, 11.6599302, 0.0],
 [25.0, 0.0, 11.6599302, 10.0],
 [26.0, 11.6599302, 0.0, 10.0],
 [27.0, 27.9121876, 27.9121876, 0.0],
 [28.0, 27.9121876, 27.9121876, 10.0],
 [29.0, 9.77920055, 9.77920055, 0.0],
 [30.0, 9.77920055, 9.77920055, 10.0]]
```

Comment: can you add some input and expected output?

Comment: For binary search, use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module. I'm not going to bother attempting to decipher your improperly formatted code.

Comment: Are the first elements *strictly* increasing, or can there be duplicates? And are the first elements in the X-sublists always 1, 2, 3, etc, i.e., consecutive integers like your example suggests?

Comment: They are strictly increasing and no duplicates.

Comment: Great, then my favored solution works :-). Please also say it in the question text.

Comment: Oops, sorry, actually it's not yet guaranteed to work, for example if x contains [42,1,2,3] and y contains [42,9,9,9]. Because by looking only at the first elements, I'd filter the [42,1,2,3] out even though I shouldn't. Can a case like this happen, or is judging by the first element ok?

Comment: I am trying to remove the whole sublist on the basis of first element as other elements in the sublist are not different in y as compared to x.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I am using the equivalent to x.remove(y[i])

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: A small question: In most of the answers given below, you are comparing two sublists. Exactly how does the comparison will work? Will it compare the first elemnts fo the sublists only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bisection can work, but another easy solution is to use a `set`:

```
y_set = set(tuple(v) for v in y)
```

Note that the `list`s have to be turned into something immutable.

Now simply generate the result:

```
z = [v for v in x if tuple(v) not in y_set]
```

This might look very similar to your initial solution, but the lookups here are much faster.

@StefanPochmann has a good point that you might want to base your lookup on something more specific than the whole vector, such as just the first element. The question wasn't very clear about that (only stating those are sorted).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, use [bisect.bisect_left](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) to find the the matches and delete:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

for ele in y:
    ind = bisect_left(x, ele)
    if ind < len(x) -1 and x[ind][0] == ele[0]:
        del x[ind]
```

If you look at the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py) you can see the code used for bisect_left:

```
def bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.

    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e < x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e >= x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just before the leftmost x already there.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if a[mid] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return lo
```

You can adapt that into your own code:

```
def intersection(x, y):
    for ele in y:
        lo = 0
        hi = len(x)
        while lo < hi:
            mid = (lo+hi)//2
            if x[mid] < ele:
                lo = mid+1
            else:
                hi = mid
        if lo < len(x) - 1 and x[ind][0] == ele[0]:
            del x[lo]
    return x

print(len(intersection(x,y)))
20
```

If you have dupes then you will need to use remove. Checking the first elements for an exact match is `if lo < len(x) - 1 and x[ind][0] == ele[0]:` but if you were using remove I don't see how that could work, just because the first elements matched does not mean `y[i]` was in `x` so `x.remove` would fail. So if you are only matching first elements then you can you can change your logic and just iterate over `x` putting all first elements from each sublist in a set and using a generator expression to update x.

```
st = {sub[0] for sub in y}

x[:] = (sub for sub in x if sub[0] not in st)
```

Comment: Be careful with possible duplicates. You might want to turn it around and walk over `x`, bisecting `y` to determine if the entry needs to be removed.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien,  I have no idea what the OP's data is actually like so this is just an idea on how to use bisect, the exact implementation is up to the OP.

Comment: @Padraic Since x and y are strictly increasing, I wrote a mergesort-like solution now, i.e., walking over x and y in parallel. Do you know whether numpy has something like that? (I ask because I saw you post good numpy stuff before)

Comment: @StefanPochmann. The default sort is quicksort but you can use heapsort or mergesort with np.sort

Comment: @Padraic Darn, sorry I was unclear. I don't mean sorting, as they're sorted already. I mean just the *merging* part of mergesort. I walk over x here and append its sublists to z. And I keep a pointer into y and just tag it along appropriately. I could imagine numpy having something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the first elements for filtering:

```
ykeys = set(zip(*y)[0])
z = [s for s in x if s[0] not in ykeys]
```

Python 3 versions:

```
ykeys = set(list(zip(*y))[0])
ykeys = {s[0] for s in y}
```

If judging by the first element alone is not enough:

```
yset = set(map(tuple, y))
return [s for s in x if tuple(s) not in yset]
```

On my weak laptop, with a test of your size, the first solution takes about 0.4 seconds and the second solution takes about 1 second. Not that surprising, since [`set` lookups average O(1)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)).

Here's a third version, and this one might be the most interesting because it doesn't just let Python do the job and because it's closer to what you intended but even better:

```
yi, last = 0, len(y) - 1
z = []
for s in x:
    while s > y[yi] and yi < last:
        yi += 1
    if s != y[yi]:
        z.append(s)
```

This walks over `x`, and "in parallel" walks over `y`. Similar to the merge step of merge-sort. With `yi` we point into `y`, and we increase it as needed. Thus we have overall linear time, as we only walk over `x` from start to end and also over `y` from start up to end. My laptop takes about 0.6 seconds for this, which is faster than my second solution! (It's not fair to compare it to my first solution, since that one only looks at the first elements).